# 301 Redirect in Sitecore or IIS URL Rewrite

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting, iis-7, sitecore

I am working on one Sitecore project on 301 redirect for our website. Right now our redirect chain is

http://example.com/  >>  http://www.example.com  >>  https://www.example.com  >>  https://www.example.com/en

Our company recommendation is to change it in one redirect 
Example.

http://example.com/   >>  https://www.example.com/en

http://www.example.com >> https://www.example.com/en

https://www.example.com >> https://www.example.com/en

Is there any way that I can achieve this thing in sitecore  or IIS URL Rewrite? If yes then How?
Thank you for any small help.